# Inexplicable error in Java using Derby databases

Tags: java, derby

I have code that is supposed to be querying a Derby database, but doesn't. Even worse, it is supposed to print the error messages **on separate lines**, but even fails to do that. Here is a snippet of my code (where I am having the problem):

```
try
    {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL);
        //setting up the statement to handle our initial query
        statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT TripNumber,AverageSpeed FROM " +
                "BikeTripRecords WHERE TripNumber=(SELECT count(TripNumber) FROM " +
                "BikeTripRecords)");
        //initializing maxShowableRecords depending on the number of BikeTrips already
        //recorded to the database
        if (!resultSet.next())
        {
            System.err.println("There was a problem processing your query.");
            System.out.println("This error occurred on line 86");
        }
        else
        {
            tripCount = resultSet.getInt(1);
            this.maxShowableRecords = (((x < tripCount) && (x > 1)) ? x : 
                tripCount);
            lastTripSpeed = resultSet.getDouble(2);

        }
        //getting information about their trip history (and their last trip)
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM BikeTripAnalysis");
        System.out.println("This error occurred on line 98");
        if (!resultSet.next())
        {
            System.err.println("There was a problem processing your query.");
        }
        else
        {
            //storing the values in the view to variables so that we don't have to keep
            //querying the database
            minSpeed = resultSet.getDouble(1);
            maxSpeed = resultSet.getDouble(2);
            avgSpeed = resultSet.getDouble(3);
            resultSet.close();
            //forming the statement to display
            messageToDisplay = String.format("Out of the %d trips you have " +
                    "recorded, these are your stats:\n\nMinimum Speed == " +
                    "%f\nMaximum Speed == %f\nAverage Speed == %.2f\n\nYour Last " +
                    "Speed == %.2f", tripCount, minSpeed, maxSpeed, avgSpeed,
                    lastTripSpeed);
            if ((lastTripSpeed == minSpeed) && (tripCount > 1))
            {
                messageToDisplay += "Your last average speed was your worst. You " +
                        "can do better!!";
            }
            else 
            {
                if ((lastTripSpeed == maxSpeed) && (tripCount > 1))
                {
                    messageToDisplay += "\n\nYou have set a new speed record!! " +
                            "Keep on keeping on!!";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (lastTripSpeed < avgSpeed)
                    {
                        messageToDisplay += "\n\nYou are below your average. Step" +
                                " it up!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        messageToDisplay += "\n\nYou are above your average. Keep." +
                                " It. Up!!";
                    }
                }
                //showing the user this message
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, messageToDisplay);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Adding insult to injury is the fact that the MessageDialog is showing when it is NOT supposed to.

In fact, I get something like this:

```
There was a problem processing your query.This error occurred on line 86

This error occurred on line 98
```

Comment: OK ... so what does it actually output?

Comment: I freaking knew that I should have just relied on the object-oriented database that Java provides by default.

Comment: Mike - if you want help, you will need to answer my question.  Otherwise, we are just wasting time here.  StackExchange is not the right place to post complaints about Java ...

Comment: (And Java doesn't provide ANY database by default.  They are all 3rd-party products ... with respect to Java SE, EE, ME ...)

Comment: Yes, it does. It provides Object serialization which serializes Object to byte form for storage in a file (database).

Comment: Mike - Java object serialization is not a database.  Or at least not what anyone who understood what they are talking about would call a database.  And besides, it is almost certainly NOT the correct solution for your problem ... for a number of reasons.  Stick with JDBC.

Comment: The file that the Objects get saved to is. (What is a database?)

Comment: Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database.  A database that is worthy of the name provides the ability to do queries and updates.  A file of serialized objects doesn't.  It is just a bag of ... stuff.

Comment: Oy. Mike, take a breath. Slow down. Do one thing at a time. Write code that runs the very first query against your database, test it and make it work. Don't go any further until that part is solid. Only then should you move on to the next bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the query. If I would have said something like SELECT count(TripNumber) FROM BikeTripRecords, I could have gotten the TripNumber, and then I should have said SELECT AverageSpeed FROM BikeTripRecords WHERE TripNumber = (SELECT max(TripNumber) FROM BikeTripRecords) for the lastTripSpeed. I should have taken a break from the code, came back, and then it would have been this obvious. D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

The error messages you are getting are due to queries not matching any rows in the database.  They mean that either:

- your queries are wrong, or
- the programs / processes that are inserting / updating the data are wrong, or
- the data you are inserting is wrong.

---

More specifically:

```
    SELECT TripNumber,AverageSpeed FROM " +
            "BikeTripRecords WHERE TripNumber=(SELECT count(TripNumber) FROM " +
            "BikeTripRecords)
```

That query will only return something if there is a `BikeTripRecord` whose `TripNumber` is equal to the count of all trip records.  Presumably you are trying to fetch the last / latest record.  If so, that query is at best "fragile".  If trip records are deleted or there is a "hole" in the trip number sequence, then the query might give you the wrong record or no record at all.

```
    SELECT * FROM BikeTripAnalysis
```

If this one gives you no results, then the table is empty.

---

In short, your problems seem to be problems with your queries and your application design, and not with either Derby or Java.

I suggest that you look at what data you've actually got in the database, and try executing those queries using Derby's query tool.  (I assume it has one ...)

Comment: I am not inserting any data (only retrieving it!), and I have tested the query on w3schools.org (it works there).

Comment: I don't see why my error messages are not displaying as according to the code I have typed, or why the MessageDialog is even showing at all...

Comment: Well, if you look at the code that you typed, it is pretty obvious that the dialog can only displayed if the second query produces some results.  Look at the nesting of the `if` statements!!

Comment: Mike - you need to change your attitude to this.  Being angry / frustrated / resentful that the program is not doing what you want it to won't help solve the problem.  The way to solve it is to carefully and thoughtfully examine what you have written, work out *why* it is wrong, and fix it.  (Denying that it is wrong is ... unproductive.)